# JPA Entity with Ignite Casts to wrong type upon save and flush

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, ignite

I'm having a major blocking issue with JPA Repositories `saveAndFlush` method. I'm pretty much new to JPA so apologies if this seems like a stupid post.

The error I'm receiving is to do with typecasting:
`org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Value conversion failed [column=USERROLE, from=[B, to=java.lang.Integer]`

The full exception is:

```
User Located: Admin
Group found: Johns Group 1
2022-08-05 13:00:23.918 ERROR 5813 --- [r-#75%ignite-1%] o.a.i.i.p.odbc.jdbc.JdbcRequestHandler   : Failed to execute SQL query [reqId=59, req=JdbcQueryExecuteRequest [schemaName=PUBLIC, pageSize=1024, maxRows=0, sqlQry=update PUBLIC.enduser set dept=?, login=?, name=?, password=?, pwdChanged=?, role=?, userRole=? where id=?, args=Object[] [1, admin, Admin, xxx, false, Admin, [-84, -19, 0, 5, 115, 114, 0, 45, 99, 111, 109, 46, 115, 101, 101, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116, 111, 114, 46, 105, 99, 99, 116, 118, 46, 100, 97, 116, 97, 115, 116, 111, 114, 101, 46, 109, 111, 100, 101, 108, 46, 85, 115, 101, 114, 82, 111, 108, 101, -36, 117, 121, -30, 61, 20, 43, -78, 2, 0, 4, 76, 0, 4, 78, 97, 109, 101, 116, 0, 18, 76, 106, 97, 118, 97, 47, 108, 97, 110, 103, 47, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 59, 76, 0, 2, 105, 100, 116, 0, 19, 76... and 694 more], 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101], stmtType=UPDATE_STMT_TYPE, autoCommit=false, partResReq=false, super=JdbcRequest [type=2, reqId=59]]]

org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Value conversion failed [column=USERROLE, from=[B, to=java.lang.Integer]
```

Here's my `UserRole` class

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Temporal;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Entity(name = "UserRole")
@Table(name = "user_role" , schema = "public")

public class UserRole implements Serializable{

    public UserRole(){

    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name" , unique = true)
    private String Name = "";

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "enduser" ,
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "UserRole" ,
                referencedColumnName = "id"
            )
    )
    List<User> users;

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_privilege" ,
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
             name = "role" ,
             referencedColumnName = "id"
        ) ,
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
             name = "privilege" ,
             referencedColumnName = "id"
        )
    )
    List<Privilege> permissions;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public List<Privilege> getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }

    public void setPermissions(List<Privilege> permissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

}
```

The repository interface:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import com.mycompany.myapp.model.UserRole;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRoleRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRole, Integer> {

}
```

This is my unit test function:

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void addUserToGroup() {

        User user = this.getUser();
        System.out.println("User Located: " + user.getName());

        UserRole group = userRoleRepository.getOne(1);

        System.out.println("Group found: " + group.getName());

        user.setUserRole(group);

        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

        System.out.println("Saved User Role to User");
    }
```

User class as per requested:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "enduser", schema = "PUBLIC")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private boolean pwdChanged;


    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "dept")
    private Department department;

    @JoinColumn(name="UserRole")
    private UserRole userRole;

    public UserRole getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(UserRole userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), user.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post code for User class?

Comment: Yeah buddy, il add it to the post

Comment: @Nemanja I've added the User class :)

Comment: What kind of `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` are you using for Apache Ignite? Hibernate ORM has no dialect out of the box, so this could very well be a problem in the implementation you are using. Or are you using Hibernate OGM?